# Publishing events to azure event grid via azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I want to publish an event to azure event grid from an an azure function. Other azure functions would consume the events down the line.

Is it possible to fire an event grid event using only azure functions?

Comment: Did you see this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-output?tabs=csharp

Comment: Also, check the sample here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/samples/Extensions/EventGrid/EventGridFunction.cs

Comment: I suppose you've  read the docs already and googled around? So what still makes you ask this question? Are the docs maybe unclear regarding this point or do I not understand the question?

Comment: There was a document that said event grid output was not supported by functions. it does seem to work using the link provided. Thanks for the help Shyju!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily build event-based architecture with help of [Azure Event Grids](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview).

There are two key points for integrating [Event Grid with Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid), have a look on the documentations where we can interact with multiple languages.

1. [Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=python%2Cbash)
2. [Output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-output?tabs=python)

EventGridPublisherClient, EventGridEvent are the clients we use in Python, we import them from azure.eventgrid

Below is the way we handle events in python

```
key = os.environ["EG_ACCESS_KEY"]
endpoint = os.environ["EG_TOPIC_HOSTNAME"]

# authenticate client
credential = AzureKeyCredential(key)
client = EventGridPublisherClient(endpoint, credential)
```

For more information refer to [Python Source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventgrid/azure-eventgrid/samples/publish_samples/publish_event_grid_events_to_custom_topic_sample.py) from Azure SDK for Python.